# Imaginary part of $f_m$ tends to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Does anybody have an idea how to show that for $|x|< \pi$ the imaginary part of the following sequence of functions $f_m$ tends to zero for $m \rightarrow \infty.$

$$f_m(x):=\left( \frac{e^{-ix}-1}{-ix} \right)^m \left( \sum_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{\left|e^{-ix}-1 \right|^{2m}}{|x+ 2 \pi l |^{2m}} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

So I want to show that $Im(f_m)|_{(-\pi,\pi)} \rightarrow 0.$ Unfortunately, I don't get anywhere because I don't know how to estimate the imaginary part of this product there.

The question is part of a longer proof in analysis.

Answer (score 0):

HELP TO FIND THE IMAGINARY PART YOU ASK.-I give you just the way to can estimate what you want.[image]

Now you have to use Newton bynomial to developed $w^m$ and separate real and imaginary parts which is simply tedious but not difficult.(Optional maybe use formule $(\cos x + i sin x)^m = cos(m)x + i sin(mx)$ but care with the expression of of $e^{-ix}-1$)